# JBoss Rules 5 and "static" facts

Tags: drools

I am designing a system in which I plan to use Drools 5. The system has several hundred facts that are read from a database. These facts are the same for each session. How can I create a session where I DON'T have to load these facts for each new session? Is there a way to cache them at the KnowledgeBase level?

Thanks in advance for any and all relevant responses.

Earnie!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **stateful sessions**.

Note that they aren't multi-threaded, but with a `ThreadLocal` you can initialize just 1 per thread.